# HMM for sequence classification in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

I have a dataset which includes sequence of DNA nucleotides (A,C,G,T) and each sequence has a gene index that is binary. i.e

[image]

I'm trying to classify unknown sequence by using a hidden markov model in R. However, I have trouble with using HMM package. Actually, I'm planning to fit a hmm model for binary class 1 and 0. 
- I'm not sure what will be the states and symbols. 
- How should I give the transition and emission prob. matrix? By using the training data or the model finds it itself?
- Probably the next step should be apply viterbi algorithm?

If you help by giving an example R code I will be very happy!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use a HMM for this problem?

Comment: Because I saw in the literature HMM is one of the most common method for sequence classfication problems. Therefore, I would like to compare its performance with my proposed method.